# Getting a memory physical to pid mapping in linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, kernel

Is there a way in Linux to get which process a certain physical address belongs to? I read about /proc/pid/pagemap but this is for virtual to physical translations. I was wondering if there is a way to get, for each physical page, which process this page belongs to?

For example: physical page 1 belongs to the kernel
physical page 2 belongs to

etc ...

Comment: Do remember that a physical page can belong to several processes.

Comment: Yes, I am talking for a specific point in time

Comment: Even in a specific point in time a physical page can still belong to several processes. Think about shared memory and library code.

Comment: you are right! well it will be nice if I can get this information too. Is there a way to know if a physical page is part of the kernel or a shared library

Comment: Anyway, if `/proc/pid/pagemap` contains virtual to physical translations, you could read `pagemap` for every pid and compute which physical frames belong to which pid. However, as noted before, given a frame, you'll get back a list of pids. Of course you have to have superuser powers to do this.

Comment: yeah this was actually my last resort :) but I was hoping if there is a tool that can already do that

Comment: Sometimes these high specialized accesses to kernel functions are not implemented through syscals or IOCTLs. Most of the time reading/writing files in /proc is the only and correct way to accomplish some tasks. Utilities like `ps`, `top`, `netstat` and others do this all the time.